# python http request stream response from google functions

Tags: python

I have a google function that gets data of few websites
with http request.

I want to send the data back as it comes in and not wait for all of it.
I was thinking streaming the data should work. 
But I have no idea how to do it
not on server or client side.

I already trade 20 example of google and non worked for me.

Tried:

```
response.write
response.send
```

and

```
import json
import requests

r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/stream/20', stream=True)

for line in r.iter_lines():

    # filter out keep-alive new lines
    if line:
        decoded_line = line.decode('utf-8')
        print(json.loads(decoded_line))
```

Not sure which side I am doing wrong the client or server but this not working.

Anyone know how to do streaming data on python from http request / to http res?